# Center image atop another image

Tags: html, css

I need to center an image atop another image, both vertically and horizontally. Specifically, I am trying to position a preloader gif atop a thumbnail.

I am after a **CSS** solution with **IE** compatibly and **without hard-coded fixed values**.

```css
body {
    background-color:#180e0b;
 font-family:DejaVu Sans Mono ;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: white;
}

.text {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

.thumb {
 position: absolute;
}

.loading {
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">Doomero</div>
    <div class="image">
  <img class="thumb" src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/thumb.png"/>
  <img class="loading" src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/rolling.gif"/>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct. This is the changed CSS Code:

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.thumb {
  display: block;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```css
body {
  background-color:#180e0b;
  font-family:DejaVu Sans Mono ;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
}

.text {
  float:left;
  padding-right: 6px;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.thumb {
  display: block;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Doomero</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/thumb.png"/>
    <img class="loading" src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/rolling.gif"/>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: but this assumes the `.loading` gif's size is 16x16px...  It might well be, but that's not given in the question

Comment: Tested in IE8 and it works fine. But when running from inside a c# WebBrowser control, the preloader is centered on the page instead of the thumb... any ideas?

Comment: @livin_amuk Can you provide more insight? C# Web Browser Control under Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, in Visual Studio. The WebBrowser has default settings.

Comment: @livin_amuk The VS browser isn't much powerful man. So that's the reason. You don't need to worry.

Comment: Haha I see, well I do need to worry because my entire program depends on the WebBrowser control...

Comment: @livin_amuk Oh oh... Lemme check that.

Comment: Replacing `display:inline-block` with `float:left;` fixed the issue, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you do not want to use fixed sizes and assuming that the thumbnail image is going to be larger than the loading image, you can try the following css3. This should work for most modern browsers IE9+.

```
.image {
    position:relative;
}
.thumb {
    display: block;
}
.loading {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50px);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```